# Counting nodes in two different subtrees in clojure

Tags: clojure, tree-traversal, subtree

Very new to Clojure and I haven't got a clue how to do this, i need to traverse a premade binary search tree and count the number of nodes in 2 difference subtrees like this question

https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/116/11615.pdf

Thank you for any help at all, Just need a push to get started

```
(defn familytree [tree i x]
  (cond
    (= (first(tree) i) )
      (count (zip/children))

    (= (first(tree) x))
      (count (zip/children))

    :else
      (familytree (rest tree)x i)
      ))
```

Input data
`(def test1 '[ 1 [ 2 [ 4 [8 9 ] 5 [ 10 11 ]] 3 [ 6 [ 12 13 ] 7 [ 14 15 ]]]])`

Comment: Use recursion for a recursive data structure.

Comment: I understand what i need to do, but i lack the knowledge in clojure to be able to write it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cameron

Start with deciding which Clojure persistent data type you will store the information in. Once that is decided:

- Take a look at Clojure [zippers](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/zipper).
- Take a look at Clojure [walk](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html)
- As you know about recursion, depending on how big a tree it is, you may elect to forego somethings like a zipper for straight forward recursion. In this case `for`, `loop` and `reduce` may be applicable.

**Updated**

Here is my understanding of the requirements:

1. Input tree will be in a vector/nested vector structure
2. Each vector in the tree has a 'node identifier' (in your case a number)
3. Require a function that counts the children for a node when a node matches some criteria
4. Should be able to specify multiple nodes for which counts will be returned

Given that, I've decided to use a `zipper` as it reasonably demonstrates the break down of logic to attain the requirement goals. I've also abstracted aspects to make it so the predicate for counting children may change.

You will need to read up on `clojure.zip` (there is a wealth of information on the inter-web for this.

**The Counter**
Now that the core traversal is covered (`zippers`) lets start with the counting function. As per requirements: regardless on how I arrive at a node I want to count the children of the node:

```
(defn count-children-at-node
  "Takes a zipper location and counts
  elements of it's chidren vector. Uses flatten on the
  children to sequence all the elements for counting.
  Returns a tuple identifiying the node and it's children count"
  [loc]
  (let [cnodes (zip/right loc)]
    [:node (zip/node loc)
     :count (if (nil? cnodes) ; test for no children
              0
              (count (flatten (zip/node cnodes))))]))
```

**The Workhorse** 
This is where traversal occurs. It will be exhaustive so as to find all possible nodes of interest. Counts will also be inclusive (see results below). I also want to accumulate my results and have a flexible predicate function to test for inclusion in the results:

```
(defn find-nodes-to-count
  "Accumulate results of performing a reduction function on a node in
  the tree that matches the predicate criteria"
  [acc predfn redfn loc]
  (if (zip/end? loc)
    acc
    (if (predfn (zip/node loc))
      (recur (conj acc (redfn loc)) predfn redfn (zip/next loc))
      (recur  acc predfn redfn (zip/next loc)))))
```

**The Wrapper**
With my core counter and traversal mechanisms in place, use a easy wrapping function to exercise the core:

```
(defn nodes-counter
  "Takes a tree collection and variable number of node identifiers
  and return an accumulation of tuples, each identifying the node and it's children
  count"
  [coll & nodevals]
  (find-nodes-to-count
    []                                  ; accumultator
    #(contains? (into #{} nodevals) %)  ; predicate function
    count-children-at-node              ; reduction function
    (zip/vector-zip coll)))             ; the tree collection
```

**Test/Verify**
Some REPL examples of calling `nodes-counter` with node identifier variations:

```
(def mytree [1 [2 [4 [8 9] 5 [ 10 11 ]] 3 [ 6 [ 12 13 ] 7 [ 14 15 ]]]])

(nodes-counter mytree 16)  ; => []
(nodes-counter mytree 15)  ; => [[:node 15 :count 0]]
(nodes-counter mytree 2 4) ; => [[:node 2 :count 6] [:node 4 :count 2]]
(nodes-counter mytree 4 2) ; => [[:node 2 :count 6] [:node 4 :count 2]]
```

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand this language, I've given a crack with some of the stuff i know just tell me where im going wrong

`(defn familytree [tree i x]
  (cond
    (= (first(tree) i) )
      (count (zip/children))

    (= (first(tree) x))
      (count (zip/children))

    :else
      (familytree (rest tree)x i)
      ))
`

Comment: @CameronChappell Put what code you've got up in your question so others may opine. Also, include a small example of the data (in the target Clojure data type). I'll be able to take a look a bit later.